# Bootstrap: How is this clearfix supposed to work?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following through on this [Bootstrap tutorial](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php), and not really getting their example on using clearfix. Before adding clearfix, the html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Grid System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    p{
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        background: #f2f2f2;
      }
  </style>
</head> 

</body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 1</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 2</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 3</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 5</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 6</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 7</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 8</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 9</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 10</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 11</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 12</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After adding the clearfix:

```
</body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"><p class="fat">Box 1</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 2</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 3</p></div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block" style="clear: both"></div> 
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p class="fat">Box 5</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 6</p></div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 7</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 8</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 9</p></div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 10</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 11</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><p>Box 12</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've made two of the divs (Box 1 and Box 5) larger using the .fat class to see what the effect of clearfix is supposed to be. But after comparing the two (with and without clearfix), I don't get any visible result:
[image: clearfix not working?]

If I'm not wrong, what clearfix is supposed to achieve is for the empty clearfix div to clear the big Box 1 float so that Box 4 will fall under it in column 1 and not get flushed to its side. This I can achieve my setting `style="clear: both"` in the Box 4 as well as Box 7 divs:
[image: cleared 4 and 7]

I'm not too sure because the tutorial didn't give any screenshots of the expected results, so is this what clearfix is supposed to achieve, or am I just understanding the whole thing wrong? If so, why does adding the clearfix divs have no effect whatsoever? I'd appreciate very much if anyone could clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you got it perfectly right.

Comment: Do you get a better result if you put the class on the div that you want content to clear? class="col-md-4 clearfix"

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/4P28D7cjb9 -?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan By that you mean the second picture is the desired result? @wunth Nope, the result is no different from clearfix in the empty div. @Dmitriy that seems quite different from the example I'm working on...and if I understand the CSS correctly the divs are not actually floating (since there's the line `float: none`)?